# Vim(script)L File Browser / Hyperlink

Tags: vim

From the command line, if you type "vim some_directory/", vim will open a sort of file browser, where you can navigate through your directory structure by moving up or down with "j"  and "k", and selecting with "enter" until you get to and open a file.

I'd like to write a function for vim in VimL that generates a (for now) arbitrary list of file names in your sub-directories and lists them in that file browser-like form mentioned above, where you can navigate to a file in the list by pressing "j" or "k" and selecting it (opening it, to edit) by pressing "enter".

Is that possible with VimL? If so, how? Bear in mind I'm interested in implementing the file-browser functionality, I've already figured out getting a list of file names.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This sounds similar to the sort of thing that [NERDtree](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658) does. Have you looked at that?

Comment: Yea it is pretty similar, but NERDtree doesn't provide me necessarily the same functionality that I'm looking for. I'd like to have my plugin display just like NERDtree though! I'm looking through the nerdtree source code to see if i can figure it out.

Comment: Ok looking at the NERDtree code makes me think this is much more complicated than I'm really interested in getting into lol. A small tangent then... with vimscript how do I open a new window, in the way that NERDtree does?

Comment: I don't know, I've never got that deep into Vim scripting. :) Your description just made me think of NERDtree, which I guess has all the answers if you look closely enough.

Comment: Do you want a project manager? See [Project.vim)(http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=69). As you said, what you ask for is actually a complex task best tackled by looking at existing scripts.

Answer (score 1):

In Vim, this is implemented by *scratch buffers*; i.e. you open a new buffer with `:new`, populate it with Vimscript (`:normal i...` or `:call setline(1, "foo")`), and `:setlocal nomodifiable`.

Usually, the following settings are also applied:

```
:setlocal buftype=nofile bufhidden=wipe nobuflisted noswapfile
```

To implement actions, use `:map <buffer>` to define special mappings just for that scratch buffer, e.g.

```
:nnoremap <buffer> <CR> :echo "you selected: " getline('.')
```

Voila!